# Vue.js && Shopware 6 is there any possibility to pass the target element through @input?

Tags: vue.js, shopware6

I'm trying to build a custom cms-element with multiple textfields.

Therefor I adapted the code of th cms-text element and customized it.

Whenever I want to change the value of one textfield, all the other values are changing too.

Is there any possibility to pass the target through @input/@blur?

All elements are similar and looks like this:

```
<sw-text-editor
                            v-model="element.config.information.value"
                            :allow-inline-data-mapping="true"
                            sanitize-input
                            @input="onInput"
                            @blur="onBlur"
                        />
```

vue:

```
onBlur(content) {
            this.emitChanges(content);
        },

        onInput(content) {
            this.emitChanges(content);
        },

        emitChanges(content) {
            if (content !== this.element.config.productName.value && this.element.config.productName.source !== 'mapped') {
                this.element.config.productName.value = content;
                this.$emit('element-update', this.element);
                console.log(this.element)
            }

            if(content !== this.element.config.subtitle.value && this.element.config.subtitle.source !== 'mapped'){
                this.element.config.subtitle.value = content;
                this.$emit('element-update', this.element);
                return;
            }

            if(content !== this.element.config.information.value && this.element.config.information.source !== 'mapped'){
                this.element.config.information.value = content;
                this.$emit('element-update', this.element);
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the original event using `$event` in inline event handlers and pass more variables, like the property name, that way.

```html
<sw-text-editor
    v-model="element.config.information.value"
    :allow-inline-data-mapping="true"
    sanitize-input
    @input="onChange('information', $event)"
    @blur="onChange('information', $event)"
/>
<sw-text-editor
    v-model="element.config.productName.value"
    :allow-inline-data-mapping="true"
    sanitize-input
    @input="onChange('productName', $event)"
    @blur="onChange('productName', $event)"
/>
```

```js
onChange(propertyName, content) {
    if (content !== this.element.config[propertyName].value && this.element.config[propertyName].source !== 'mapped') {
        this.element.config[propertyName].value = content;
        this.$emit('element-update', this.element);
    }
}
```